# Tesseract Shapeclustering

Tags: tesseract

The documentation of Tesseract says:

> shapeclustering should not be used except for the Indic languages.

However, if I use it in an alphanumeric language, I seem to get better results distinguishing similar characters like the `2` and the `Z`.

Why is that?